# jquery: how to remove a tag with everything in it

Tags: jquery, html

When clicked on the second a tag with remove class, I want to delete this entire part!

HTML:

```
<div class="tr">
            <div class="tbl-cell">
                <input id="txt_1" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="tbl-cell">
                <a href="#" class="remove" ></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I do that in jquery?
I tried using this code:

JQuery:

```
    $("body").on("click",".remove", function(e){ 
        if( x > 1 ) {
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                x--; 
        }
```

But it only deletes the second inner div which holds the a tag with remove class.

Comment: What difference does it make to the answer?

Comment: @Muhammad Osmond, It keeps the number of elements which I add then remove! any way, as Barmar mentioned, It doesn't make any difference here ...

Comment: Just wondering, why did he use if statement on the click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest `div` element with class `tr`.

```
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
    if (x > 1) {
        $(this).closest('div.tr').remove();
        //                 ^^
        x--;
    }
```

.closest()

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

to remove the entire row, not just the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).parents(".tr").remove();
```

or

```
$(this).closest(".tr").remove();
```